# Mockito Assert resulting NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I am writing a simple test case but getting a null pointer exception in the return value.
Although when I debug the actual mocking is working , and my main code is also being triggered

**My Test Case**

```
  @Test
  public void testEmptyRequests() {
     List<MyPojo> list = new ArrayList();
     String env = "env-stub";
     when(myService.fetchRecords(env)).thenReturn(list);
     Assert.assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(0), myController.process(env, 1));
 }
```

**My Method**

```
      @Async
      public Integer process(String environment, Integer id) {
      List<MyPojo> list = myService.fetchRecords(environment);
      if (list == null || list .isEmpty()) {
          log.info("[0] claims to process");
         return 0;
        }
            // Other logic here, Not relevant to this test case
     }
```

Comment: you are setting expectations for `when(myService.pullRequests(env)).thenReturn(list);` but your method is calling `myService.fetchRecords(environment)`

Answer (score 0):

change your test method to this:

```
    @Test
    public void testEmptyRequests() {
        List<MyPojo> list = new ArrayList();
        String env = "env-stub";
        when(myService.fetchRecords(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(list);
        Assert.assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(0), myController.process(env, 1));
 }
```

You should mock the method you are using inside your code.

Comment: Sorry , that  incorrect method name in "when" block was a typo, I have corrected it in the question now . I am still getting that issue .  Thanks

Comment: are you injecting the mocked myService in the test?

Comment: Yes  I am injecting the @Mockbean